# "QSQLite Error: Database is locked" when trying to access a database

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, qt, qsqldatabase, database-locking

I am working on a Windows application that performs a certain operation X on a database.

It:

- Is developed in Qt
- Uses QSQLite as a database engine.
- Is a single-threaded application, i.e., the tables are processed sequentially.

However, as the DB size grows (in number of tables and records), this processing becomes slower. The result of this operation X is written in a separate results table in the same DB. The processing being done is immaterial to the problem, but in basic terms, here's what it does:

- Read a row from `Table_X_1`.
- Read a row from `Table_X_2`.
- Do some operations on the rows (only read).
- Push the results in Table_X_Results table (this is the only write being performed on the DB).

`Table_X_1` and `Table_X_2` are identical in number and types of columns and number of rows, only the data may differ.

---

In order to improve the performance, I am trying to make the application multithreaded.

Initially I am spawning two threads (using ***Qt Concurrent Run***). The two tables can be categorized in two types, say A and B. Each thread will take care of the tables of two types. Processing within the threads remains same, i.e., within each thread the tables are being processed sequentially.

The function is such that it uses `SELECT` to fetch rows for processing, and `INSERT` to insert the result in the results table. For inserting the results, I am using transactions.

I am creating all the intermediate tables, result tables and indices before starting my actual operation. I am opening and closing connections every time. For the threads, I create and open a connection before entering the loop (one for each thread).

---

Inside my processing function, I get the following error:

> QSqlError(5, "Unable to fetch row", "database is locked")

I am getting this error when trying to read a row from the database (using `SELECT`). This is in the same function in which I'm performing my `INSERT`s into the results table. The `SELECT` and the `INSERT` are in the same transaction (begin and commit pair). For `INSERT`, I'm using prepared statement (SQLiteStatement).

---

**Reasons for seemingly peculiar things that I am doing:**

- I am using ***Qt Concurrent Run*** to create the threads, because it is straightforward to do! I have tried using QThread (not subclassing QThread, but the [other](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation) method). That also leads to the same problem.
- I am compiling with `DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=0` to avoid the application crashing. If I use the default (`DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1`), my application crashes at `SQLiteStatement::recordSet->Reset()`. Also, with the default option, the internal SQLITE sync mechanism comes into play, which may not be reliable. If the need be, I'll employ explicit sync.
- Making the application multithreaded to improve performance, and not doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/how-do-i-improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite). I'm taking care of all the optimizations recommended there.
- Using `QSqlDatabase::setConnectOptions` with `QSQLITE_BUSY_TIMEOUT=0`. A link suggested that it will prevent the database from getting locked immediately, and hence, may give my thread(s) appropriate amount of time to "die peacefully". This failed: the database got locked much more frequently than before.

---

**Observations**:

- The database goes into lock only and as soon as when one of the threads return. This behavior is consistent.
- When compiling with `DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1`, the application crashes when one of the threads returns. Call stack points at `SQLiteStatement::recordSet->Reset()` in my function, and at `winMutexEnter()` (called from `EnterCriticalSection()`) in `sqlite3.c`. This is consistent as well.
- The threads created using ***Qt Concurrent Run*** do not die immediately.
- If I use QThreads, I can't get them to return. That is to say, I feel the thread never returns even though I have connected the signals and the slots correctly.

  What is the correct way to wait for threads, and how long it takes them to die?
- The thread that finishes execution never returns, it has locked the database and hence the error.
- I checked for `SQLITE_BUSY`, and tried to make the thread sleep, but could not get it to work. What is the correct way to sleep in Qt (for threads created with ***Qt Concurrent Run*** or QThreads)?
- When I close my connections, I get this warning:

> QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'DB_CONN_CREATE_RESULTS' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.*

Is this of any significance? Some links suggested that this warning arises because of using local QSqlDatabase, and will not arise if the connection is made a class member. However, could it be the reason for my problem?

---

**Further experiments**:

- I am thinking of creating another database, which will only contain results table (`Table_X_Results`).

  The rationale is that while the threads will read from one DB (the one that I have currently), they will get to write to another DB. However, I may still face the same problem.

  Moreover, I read on the forums and wikis that it **IS** possible to have two threads doing read and write on the same database. So why can I not get this scenario to work?
- I am currently using SQLITE version 3.6.17. Could that be the problem? Will things be better if I used version 3.8.5?

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by [user3881651](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3881651/user3881651):

I found out that the table processing functions were opening a transaction. These functions had to go on threads. This means each thread would open a transaction.

I believe this was the problem. As the function is about to end (and thread about to return), it would try to commit to the database, and would get locked.

Now, I am opening a transaction before entering the thread loop, processing all the tables (one thread per table) and finally committing it to the database.

I have tested this behavior on more than 50 different databases, and this seems to be the solution.